# same or new API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

we are recently migrating to web api from WCF and below are the API that we are planning to migrate

public Order ValidateOrder ( Order) --> this will do some business logic and store it in local database

public Order SubmitOrder( Order) --> this will do some business logic and store it in local database and put the payload in azure bus.

So the only difference between both the API is keeping the payload in azure bus.

Now would like to know , should i have only one REST API which takes Order as input and flag doSubmit and send Order as output  or should have 2 .

which is more maintainable and as per rest standards

Comment: Always follow SOLID principles. Have 2 methods and in your actions do the needful. Tomorrow if there are requirement changes for one action, then only respective action would be impacted. So, don't create any dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have one REST API.

1. public Order SubmitOrder( Order)

First make an private method in the same method which will validate the order.
Call the private method first.If it is SUCCESS then you can Submit the same order and If it is FAILED then don't Submit the Order or Pass Proper Message Why it gets FAILED.